# VS community | проблема с изменением места установки SDK покетов и инструментов

Tags: visual-studio

[image: Хотел изменить место сохранения SDC пакетов, однако возникла проблема, просто не могу сменить данный пусть устаноовки с C на F диск]

У меня мало места на C диске поэтому хотел бы поменять расположение пакетов SDK на диск D, однако эта вкладка просто горит серым

Comment: VS и VSC - разные вещи.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я не совсем розбираюсь, это VS?

Comment: Да. VSC = visual studio code, это другая программа.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать лишь единственный известный и рабочий мне способ - удалить VSC и установить вновь. Во время установки выбрать данную вкладку и выбрать вам удобный путь